# How to center buttons in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my CSS and HTML.

```css
.btn-group button {
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* Green border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px;
  /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="button1">Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button2">About Nano/Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button3">Donate</button>
</div>
```

[image: Image Of Buttons]

I want to center these buttons under the text in the screen's center!
I have tried so many things nothing works for me.

Comment: try this `.btn-group{display:table; margin:0 auto;}`

Comment: It works without my css, but if I add my CSS I made it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `flex` on `.btn-group` and make it take `100%` of the width of the parent to stretch the div.

```css
.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.btn-group button {
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* Green border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px;
  /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="button1">Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button2">About Nano/Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button3">Donate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your css:

```css
.btn-group{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

It will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox

```
.btn-group {
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content:center; 
}
.btn-group button {

  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="button1">Faucet</button>
    <button type="button" class="button2">About Nano/Faucet</button>
    <button type="button" class="button3">Donate</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: This also seemed to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

As easy as adding this rule to style the container using `display:flex`

```
.btn-group{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;  
}
```

And this is the whole snippet:

```css
.btn-group{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;  
}

.btn-group button {
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left; /* Float the buttons side by side */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="button1">Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button2">About Nano/Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button3">Donate</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me!

Comment: please accept the answer arriving first... I see everyone just said more or less the same thing

Answer (score 0):

add `.btn-group{display: table; margin: 0 auto;}`

```css
    .btn-group{display: table; margin: 0 auto;}

    .btn-group button {
      border: 3px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      /* Green background */
      border: 1px solid green;
      /* Green border */
      color: white;
      /* White text */
      padding: 10px 24px;
      /* Some padding */
      cursor: pointer;
      /* Pointer/hand icon */
      float: left;
      /* Float the buttons side by side */
    }

    .btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
      border-right: none;
      /* Prevent double borders */
    }


    /* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

    .btn-group:after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }


    /* Add a background color on hover */

    .btn-group button:hover {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="button1">Faucet</button>
      <button type="button" class="button2">About Nano/Faucet</button>
      <button type="button" class="button3">Donate</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following CSS to your code. Display be flex then use Justify content center to get output.

```
.btn-group {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex.

```css
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-group button {
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* Green border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px;
  /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="button1">Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button2">About Nano/Faucet</button>
  <button type="button" class="button3">Donate</button>
</div>
```